# Is There a Better Replacement for ExceptionShielding?

Tags: c#, wcf, enterprise-library

Our company is making the switch from `Microsoft.Practices.Enterprise.Library` logging and exception handling to using `Log4Net`.  I removed all of the standard logging and exception handling calls, replacing them with the `Log4Net` equivalents, but when I removed the Practices Dlls, I noticed that we were using them for ExceptionShielding:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.WCF;

namespace CRM.WCFServices.LeadIntegration.ServiceContracts
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interface for systems external to CRM to interact with outbound calls.
    /// </summary>
    [ExceptionShielding("WCF Exception Shielding")]
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IOutboundIntegrationService
    {
        #region Contracts

        [OperationContract]
        [FaultContract(typeof (Common.Services.WCF.FaultContracts.ServiceFault))]
        void SendOutboundData(string entityName, Guid entityId, DateTime modifiedOn, Guid modifiedBy,
                              string crmOrganization);

        #endregion
    }
}
```

The basic question is "How can I safely remove it?" which involves answering most of these questions:

1. What does it do? - From What I've read it allows you to catch any exceptions in your WCF Service before it is returned to the client, allowing you to log the exception and create an exception that doesn't contain any security sensitive information.
2. Is it valid on an Interface (it's not referenced anywhere on the ?
3. Does Log4Net have something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, the purpose of the [Exception Shielding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648319.aspx) feature was to

1. Prevent the release of implementation detail across the service boundary, or
2. Allow the developer to be lazy and not add try/catch blocks around all service operations at the service boundary.

Make your choice.

If my memory is correct, then all you need to do is either turn `includeExceptionDetailInFaults` to false in the web.config, or to put try/catch blocks around your service methods:

```
try
{
    // service code
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Log the exception
    throw new FaultException("Unknown service failure");
}
```

Comment: Does _what_ work being declared on the interface? Are you referring to the code I posted? Obviously, that code needs to exist in the service operation code itself. You could conceivably use PostSharp to inject the above code, but there's little enough of it to just enter in each operation, perhaps inserted from a code snippet.

Comment: I was talking about my code.  I didn't think it was possible for an interface to apply any implementation, and if implementing the interface provides exception handing, seems kind of fishy to me.

Comment: Why, in general, should the interface have anything to do with the behavior? You happen to have seen an example where the attribute was placed on the interface. I'm sure it also works if the attribute is on the service class.

Comment: I would have thought that the type attribute would be required on the service class.  I guess this is an example of how you can use an interface to actually provide implementation, via an attribute.

Comment: The attribute doesn't provide implementation - it merely provides metadata. Some other piece of code (Enterprise Library) looks at the metadata and provides implementation. It could as easily have read an XML config file for the same purpose.